# PostgreSQL time range duration over time series with default end if null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to be able to calculate the duration (in seconds) between two time stamps as an aggregate over a time series using a default end_datetime if it is null.

Imagine you have something like a punch card when you puch in and out:
username, start_datetime, end_datetime

What I want is a generated time series of the last N minutes with the duration for all users that overlap within that time frame. So it would be the SUM(end_datetime - start_datetime) where you would COALESCE a default end_datetime if it is null.

So the basic pieces I think I need are:

**Generate the time interval:**

```
select TIMESTAMP '2013-01-01 12:01:00' - (interval '1' minute * generate_series(0,5)) as timestamps;
```

**COALESCE a default end_datetime**

```
COALESCE(end_datetime, NOW())
```

**Figure out the seconds difference between the start and end dates**

So if one user logged in at 11:56:50 and it is now 12:01:40 we should get a table like:

```
     timestamps          duration
-------------------------------------
 2013-01-01 12:01:00        40
 2013-01-01 12:00:00        60
 2013-01-01 11:59:00        60
 2013-01-01 11:58:00        60
 2013-01-01 11:57:00        60
 2013-01-01 11:56:00        10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t as (select '2013-01-01 11:56:50'::timestamp startt, '2013-01-01 12:01:40'::timestamp endt)

select
   timestamps,
   extract(epoch from 
   case 
      when timestamps=date_trunc('minute',startt) then date_trunc('minute',startt) + interval '1 minute' - startt
      when timestamps =date_trunc('minute',endt) then endt- date_trunc('minute',endt)
      else interval '60 seconds' end) as durations
from
   (select generate_series(date_trunc('minute',startt),date_trunc('minute',endt),'1 minute') timestamps, * from t) a
order by
   timestamps desc;

2013-01-01 12:01:00;40
2013-01-01 12:00:00;60
2013-01-01 11:59:00;60
2013-01-01 11:58:00;60
2013-01-01 11:57:00;60
2013-01-01 11:56:00;10
```

If you have multiple rows with start and end timestamp than the following will work:

```
select
   id,
   timestamps,
   extract(epoch from 
   case 
      when timestamps=date_trunc('minute',startt) then date_trunc('minute',startt) + interval '1 minute' - startt
      when timestamps =date_trunc('minute',endt) then endt- date_trunc('minute',endt)
      else interval '60 seconds' end) as durations
from
   (
      select 
      id,
      generate_series(date_trunc('minute',startt) ,
                      coalesce(date_trunc('minute',endt),date_trunc('minute',Now())),'1 minute') as timestamps,
      startt, endt
   from test
   ) a
order by
   id, timestamps desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/122b0/1)

Comment: Thanks!  I have been pulling my hair out on SQLFiddle trying to figure this out.  I had the some of the parts but couldn't imagine the whole thing put together.